# Sequence vs. MutableSequence

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing, abc, python-collections

I've been using [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) in type hints for sequences including mutable `list`s. Now I've just discovered that there is also [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence). As far as I can tell, `Sequence` is a superclass of `MutableSequence`, i.e., `Sequence` includes both mutables like `list` and immutables like `tuple`, while `MutableSequence` only includes the former.

Two questions:

- Is this correct? (I'm pretty sure it is, but I haven't found any explicit statement to this end.)
- If so, is there an immutable equivalent to `MutableSequence` that includes, e.g., `tuple` and `str`, but not `list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No — in Python, you can only define interfaces (of which `Sequence` and `MutableSequence` are two examples) in terms of the *presence* of certain methods/behaviours; you cannot define an interface in terms of the *absence* of certain methods/behaviours.

I would recommend reading the [source code for `collections.abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_collections_abc.py), which I personally find much more illuminating than the documentation.